# Silverlight Treeview item Coordinates

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

I am new to silverlight and stuck with a problem. I am trying to find out the coordinates of a treeviewitem. Can someone help me out?

Comment: May I ask you why you should need them?

Comment: I am trying a sample app where by I have two treeview for example treeview 1 has Country names and treeview 2 has flags for those countries. So on selecting a country (say "France"), a line should be drawn between treeviewitem of country and flag. I am  trying to find the coordinate and then draw a line between the treeviewitem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a way to get the coordinates.

```
GeneralTransform objGeneralTransformFlag = flagItem.TransformToVisual(Application.Current.RootVisual as UIElement);

Point pFlag = objGeneralTransformFlag.Transform(new Point(0, 0));
```

where flagItem is the treeViewItem